# How can I ensure that all my React Navigation routes have the exact same animation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I've set up some animated routes in React Native 0.59 using `react-native-navigation` and I've wanted to know what I could do to ensure the animation is the exact same for every route, regardless of the route stack.

I've tinkered with `StackActions.reset()` but it only negatively impacted the performance of my application, and removed the animations as a whole, so I chose not to use it. I figure there's probably some piece of code that I'm missing or perhaps I need to overhaul my entire routing system.

I've included some code I'm using:

This is my complete `NavigationManager.js` class:

```
import { NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";

export default class NavigationManager {

    navigator = null; // The navigator itself.

    /**
     * Function for setting the navigator (generally top reference).
     */
    static set(ref) {
        navigator = ref; // Set the navigator.
    }

    /**
     * Function for going to the desired screen.
     */
    static go(routeName, params) {
        navigator.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate( { routeName, params } ));
    }
}
```

And this my implementation in my `SwitchBoard.js` class:

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
    Portfolio : PortfolioScreen,
    Home : HomeScreen,
    Search : SearchScreen,
    Settings : SettingsScreen,
}, {
    defaultNavigationOptions : {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
    }, headerMode : "none",
    transitionConfig : () => ({
        transitionSpec : {
            duration : 400,
            easing : Theme.ANIMATION_EASING,
            timing : Animated.timing,
        }, screenInterpolator : sceneProps => {
            const { layout, position, scene } = sceneProps;
            const { index } = scene; // The index of the stack.

            const opacity = position.interpolate({
                inputRange : [index - 1, index, index + 1],
                outputRange : [0, 1, 1],
            });

            return { opacity };
        },
    }),
});

const Container = createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator({
        AppStack : AppStack,
    })
);
```

My `Screen` classes consist of basic extended React Native `Component` classes.

The animation when clicking back to the initial route (in this example, the `PortfolioScreen` route) traverses through all the routes in the stack and it's visible in the animation.

Here is a .gif image showing the error. It's the last button I press (after the red screen) that resets the stack and animates in a weird way.

[image: the animation]

Thank you in advance.